# Js create object with field or update field [short]

Tags: javascript

I noticed that most of the code consists of such fragments, where we first check for null and create an object with field or if it exists, we update the field.
Question, is it possible to write this briefly in one line? maybe with fancy `?? ?. ??=`

```
if (!obj) {
        obj= { MyField: 1 };
    } else {
        obj.MyField++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) to assign a value if none exists.

```js
let obj1 = { MyField: 5 };

obj1 ??= { MyField: 0 };
obj1.MyField++;

console.log( obj1 );

// ==========

let obj2 = null;

obj2 ??= { MyField: 0 };
obj2.MyField++;

console.log( obj2 );
```

Comment: with ??=  realy cool and shorter than writing the conditions. THX!

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional ternary operator

```
// returns new object
let obj1 = null;
obj1 = obj1 ? { MyField: obj1.MyField + 1 } : {MyField : 1};

// returns incremented value
let obj2 =  {MyField : 1};
obj2 = obj2 ? { MyField: obj2.MyField + 1 } : {MyField : 1};
```